# Why does this code not compile, although interfaces are reference types?

Tags: c#, .net

I am confused. In [Why are interfaces in .Net reference types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4638367/why-are-interfaces-in-net-reference-types) it is said that Interfaces in .Net are reference types.
The first code snippet does not compile. It says something like "T must be a reference type..."

```
    public ISomeInterface DoMagic<T>(Expression<Func<object>> action, Tuple<string, DateTime, decimal> tuple) 
    where T : ISomeInterface 
    {
      Magician m = new Magician();
      return m.Magic<T>(()=> action, tuple.Item3);
    }
```

The second compiles.

```
    public ISomeInterface DoMagic<T>(Expression<Func<object>> action, Tuple<string, DateTime, decimal> tuple) 
    where T : class, ISomeInterface 
    {
      Magician m = new Magician();
      return m.Magic<T>(()=> action, tuple.Item3);
    }
```

If Interfaces are reference types why does the first code snippet not compile?

Comment: Value types can implement interfaces too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because it's about the *real* type of the object encapsulated inside interface. 
By declaring just `ISomeInterface` , you do not define the *must* condition: T has to be a reference type.

Because I can have:

```
public interface IStructInterface {
}
public struct A : IStructInterface {
}
```

and this is a *value* type.

By defining additional constrain *class*, you declare that this *is* reference type.

Answer (score 0):

That's the error message you receive when `Magic` has a `class` constraint:

```
public ISomeInterface Magic<T>(Func<object> a, decimal d) where T:class
```

It could be better worded, but when it says "T must be a reference type...", what it actually means is "T is constrained to be a class". This code generates the same error as the OP has:

```
 class ABC {  
    public ISomeInterface DoMagic<T>(Expression<Func<object>> action, Tuple<string, DateTime, decimal> tuple)
    where T : ISomeInterface
    {
        Magician m = new Magician();
        return m.Magic<T>(() => action, tuple.Item3);
    }
}

interface ISomeInterface { }

class Magician
{
    public ISomeInterface Magic<T>(Func<object> a, decimal d) where T:class
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

> The type '`T`' must be a reference type in order to use it as parameter '`T`' in the generic type or method '`ConsoleApplication4.Magician.Magic<T>(System.Func<object>, decimal)`'