# Compile error using an interface as a generic type constraint

Tags: c#, generics

**Update:**

I'll accept that to get the code to work [Jon's answer to this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/390974/1730559) is correct.  And [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4638417/1730559) answers why an interface is treated like a reference type.

I'd still like to know what the difference is though. Why is an interface not treated like a reference type when it is a generic type constraint? Is their some design reason for this? I have a feeling the only reason may be "they just are".

**Original question:**

I am converting a class into a generic class but I found some strange behaviour with using an interface as a type parameter.  The class has a field and property which are a type of interface, for example IMagic.

```
public interface IMagic
{
    bool Magic { get; }
}

public class HasMagic
{
    private IMagic _magic;
    public IMagic Magic
    {
        get { return _magic; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _magic)
                _magic = value;
        }
    }

    public bool IsMagical
    {
        get { return _magic != null ? _magic.Magic : true; }
    }
}
```

I want to change them to instead be type T and have the class defined with the type parameter `where T : IMagic`.  Doing this though gave me a compiler error `Operator '!=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'T' and 'T'`.

```
public class HasMagic<T> where T : IMagic
{
    private T _magic;
    public T Magic
    {
        get { return _magic; }
        set
        {
            // Compiler error here!
            if (value != _magic)
                _magic = value;
        }
    }

    public bool IsMagical
    {
        // But no error here!?
        get { return _magic != null ? _magic.Magic : true; }
    }
}
```

So why doesn't the generic version work?  Shouldn't `==` and `!=` operators work for all types?

The error only occurs in the property setter though, so it got me thinking, is the `_magic` field actually really a boxed IMagic or some other reference type?  Indeed it can be set to null which should only work with nullable types.  As the test below shows an IMagic struct (MagicStruct) works fine, but why?  Changing the field and property in HasMagic to a MagicStruct gives compile errors, as you'd expect.

```
public class MagicTests
{
    [Fact]
    public void SomeMagicTest()
    {
        var mag = new HasMagic();
        Assert.True(mag.IsMagical);

        mag.Magic = new MagicClass();
        Assert.False(mag.IsMagical);

        mag.Magic = new MagicStruct();
        Assert.True(mag.IsMagical);

        mag.Magic = null;
        Assert.True(mag.IsMagical);
    }
}

public class MagicClass : IMagic
{
    public bool Magic { get { return false; } }
}

public struct MagicStruct : IMagic
{
    public bool Magic { get { return true; } }
}
```

If it's of any relevance I'm using .Net framework v4.5.2.

Comment: "So why doesn't the generic version work? Shouldn't == and != operators work for all types?" see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/390900/cant-operator-be-applied-to-generic-types-in-c

Comment: 1:`T` may or may not have `==` and `!=` operators defined. 2:`if (value != _magic)` is redundant

Comment: @IlyaLuzyanin I do understand that. But it works fine in the case of using just the interface which should have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

T is a type argument and can be a class or a struct, because of that the compiler won't let you perform actions that doesn't exist in a class or a struct. You can try it like this:

```
public T Magic
    {
        get { return _magic; }
        set
        {
            // Compiler error here!
              if (!EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(_magic, value))
                _magic = value;
        }
    }
```

Or you can just use Equals inside your code

```
 public T Magic
    {
        get { return _magic; }
        set
        {
            // Compiler error here!
            if (!value.Equals(_magic))
                _magic = value;
        }
    }
```

Comment: @kjbartel Because you are not using a generic type. You can see more info on why you can`t use the operators in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/390900/cant-operator-be-applied-to-generic-types-in-c

Comment: Well the EqualityComparer<T> version works but Equals does not as you can get a NullReferenceException if value is null.  I'm still curious as to what is happening with the interface version though as it is clearly being treated a reference type.

Comment: @kjbartel Again another of your questions is answered here in stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4638367/why-are-interfaces-in-net-reference-types

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `!=` (`==`) on generic types.

a possible solution would be made `IMagic` to implement [IComparable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.icomparable(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
public interface IMagic : IComparable
```

and then use `CompareTo`

```
 if (value.CompareTo(_magic) != 0)
```

you can write your own implementation of CompareTo method

```
 public int CompareTo(object obj) {

    }
```

**update**

if you can't edit `IMagic` try adding a property to `HasMagic` class like this

```
public Func<T, T, bool> FuncEvaluate { get; set; }
```

and then check in this way

```
  public T Magic
    {
        get { return _magic; }
        set
        {
            if (FuncEvaluate != null)
            {
                if (!FuncEvaluate(value, _magic))
                {
                    _magic = value;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
        }
    }
```

and when you decide to use the class you should set the function to compare objects maybe checking `typeof(T).IsValueType`

Comment: Unfortunately I can't change the interface as it's not mine to change.  I'm actually using INotifyPropertyChanged and need to support both class and structs.

Comment: Although interesting, !EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(_magic, value) is far simpler and cleaner. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score -1):

T can be a value type or a reference type; you didn't contrain it. The != (and ==) operator (reference comparison) is only defined for reference types, not for value types.

There are several solutions; You can constrain T to be a reference type:

```
public class HasMagic<T> where T : IMagic, class
```

You can also use Equals(). or object.ReferenceEquals().
And maybe some other solutions I didn't think of.

Edit: I just noticed you don't even need != in the setter, so this whole problem becomes mute.

Comment: the OP is using struct in his example so I doubt the code solution is relevant.

Comment: It's a short example. I do need the != in my real class.